# Delete [bootstrap-3]

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

[bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-3) is a duplicate of [twitter-bootstrap-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-3).

I don't know what the rules are in that case. Should it be deleted or put as a synonym since it has only one question?

Comment: simply remove the tag from the question and then it will have no question: problem solved

Comment: @TemaniAfif I've already removed the tag from the question, didn't know it works like that, so problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said on the comment section, removing the tag from the question did remove the tag entirely since it has only one question.